# Reading binary data in node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, binary

I am writing a JavaScript program that I am executing in the Node.js runtime environment.

I want to read binary data from a file into a buffer, but I keep running into issues.

###### Here is what I have done so far:

```
    $ cat test.js 
    > var fs = require('fs'),
    > binary = fs.readFileSync('./binary', 'binary').toString('binary');
    > process.stdout.write(binary.substring(0, 48));
```

```
    $ xxd binary
    00000000: 7f45 4c46 0201 0100 0000 0000 0000 0000  .ELF............
    00000010: 0300 3e00 0100 0000 0008 0000 0000 0000  ..>.............
    00000020: 4000 0000 0000 0000 10a0 0000 0000 0000  @...............
```

```
    $ node test.js | xxd
    00000000: 7f45 4c46 0201 0100 0000 0000 0000 0000  .ELF............
    00000010: 0300 3e00 0100 0000 0008 0000 0000 0000  ..>.............
    00000020: 4000 0000 0000 0000 10c2 a000 0000 0000  @...............
    00000030: 00                                       .
```

Notice how a 0xc2 byte is inserted at index 0x29 when reading with node. Why is that? I've stated binary encoding both to `readFileSync` and `toString`.
I've also tried ascii but then I get a different and equally wrong result.

Answer (score 56, accepted):

The `'binary'` encoding is an alias for `'latin1'`, which you clearly don't want when reading non-character data.

If you want the raw data, [don't specify an encoding at all](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_readfile_path_options_callback) (or supply `null`)*. You'll get a [`Buffer`](https://nodejs.org/api/buffer.html#buffer_class_buffer) instead of a string, which you'd then want to use directly rather than using `toString` on it.

* (Some APIs [like `fs.watch`] also accept `'buffer'`, but it's not on [the list of encodings](https://nodejs.org/api/buffer.html#buffer_buffers_and_character_encodings) and `readFileSync` doesn't say it does. [Thanks [Patrick](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1541563/patrick-roberts) for providing the list link.])

Comment: Is it just me, or this absurd?

Comment: @NathanChappell - It *seems* absurd on the face of it, but makes more sense when you get into the details. In some sense, `latin1` is an alias for `binary` rather than the other way around. Details in the [list of encodings](https://nodejs.org/api/buffer.html#buffer_buffers_and_character_encodings) linked above and on [this MDN page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DOMString/Binary).

Answer (score 13):

Just to add some more information, the reason this is happening is because you're passing a string to `stdout.write()`, which is implicitly converted back into a `Buffer` before being written, and when you do that in the Node.js REPL with this particular substring at position 0x28 of your binary file, you get the behavior you described:

```
> new Buffer('\u0010\u00a0')
<Buffer 10 c2 a0>
```

So as @T.J.Crowder correctly suggested, here's how to fix your script:

```
var fs = require('fs'),
    binary = fs.readFileSync('./binary');
process.stdout.write(binary.slice(0, 48));
```

This also uses [`Buffer#slice()`](https://nodejs.org/api/buffer.html#buffer_buf_slice_start_end) instead of `String#substring()`.