# node js read binary data

Tags: c++, node.js

I want to read the .nrp extension file in Node JS.
this is my node js code below.

```
    var fs = require('fs')

    fs.readFile('Jun24_Jun30.nrp','utf8', function(err, data) {
     if (err) throw err
     console.log(data)
    })
```

The output is coming as junk values when I try to read from node js.

**Node js Output**:
[image]

But if I try to read the same file in C++ I am getting the correct Output.

this is my C++ code below.

```
    #include <iostream>
    #include <stream>
    using namespace std;

    class ValueGet {
    public:
    int data;
    ValueGet() {
    data = 0;
    }
   };
   int main()
   {
    ValueGet vg;
    ifstream file;
    file.open("Jun24_Jun30.nrp", fstream::binary | fstream::out);
    if (!file)
    cout << "File Not Found." << endl;
    else {
    file.seekg(0);
    while (file.read((char *)&vg, sizeof(vg)))
        cout<<vg.data<<endl;
}
//system("pause");
return 0;
}
```

**C++ Output**:

[image]

I want the same output from node js also. Please help.

Thanks!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Reading binary data in node.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46441667/reading-binary-data-in-node-js)

Answer (score -2):

Try doing parsing the data or stringfy the data so that i may come up to human readable form. Thanks, i hope it will work.

```
    var fs = require('fs')          

    fs.readFile('Jun24_Jun30.nrp','utf8', function(err, data) {
    if (err) throw err
    else{
    console.log(JSON.parse(data))   //try JSON.parse(data) 
     }                              // JSON.Stringify(data)

    })
```